# iOS Firebase UI Gives many errors

Tags: ios, swift, firebaseui

I get many errors when trying to build the project with  (pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 4.0')  dependency.

**My pod file looks something like this:**

platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Core'

pod 'Firebase/Database'

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'Firebase/Storage'

pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 4.0' **(This causes a lot of errors)**

pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'

pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'

pod 'FirebaseUI/Twitter'

**Some of the errors are:**

> /Users/Home/GoogleDrive/iOS/TheBolt/Pods/Target Support Files/nanopb/nanopb-umbrella.h:1:9: Could not build module 'UIKit'

and

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:505:9: Unknown type name 'NSString'

and

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:514:50: Missing '#include '; declaration of 'Protocol' must be imported from module 'ObjectiveC.runtime' before it is required

I'm using Xcode 9 with swift 4. I tried to use swift 3.2 in build settings but the same errors still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need for (pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 4.0') along with the others. Adding it alone or just the necessary login pods solved the problem